# Run bash -c without exit

Tags: bash, mingw, msys

I'm trying to run MinGW's MSYS bash from Windows with a command in its arguments, and it's achievable with the -c switch.
For example:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0> bin\bash -c "times" 
0m0.000s 0m0.046s
0m0.000s 0m0.000s
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0>
```

With this command, bash will run, execute 'times', and exit.

Is it possible to do the same thing, but staying in a bash command line instead of exiting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0> bin\bash -c "times;/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/bash"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't know i can use a semicolon for multiple commands! doing "times;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\bash" didn't work, but instead "times;/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/bash" worked.